# Why not ~/dls instead of ~/Downloads?

Tags: linux, unix, home-directory

Most folder names in the *nix world are lower case.  It makes them easier to type in my opinion.  However, everything in my home-dir is capitalized!  Why is this?  Is it possible to change them?

The only solution I have come up with so far is putting soft links in my home dir for each folder with lower case names.

```
ln -s ~/Downloads dls
```

Furthermore, doesn't it seem weird that there are no abbreviations in the home dir?  I'm used to folder names like `dev`, `lib`, `tmp`, `var`, or `usr`.  That's right, we want to save one keystroke by shortening `user` to `usr` and three on `binary` to `bin`, but `Downloads` can't be shortened to `dls`.

Which of the following looks more like a *nix directory structure to you?

```
Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public Templates Videos
```

or

```
desk docs dls music img pub templates vids
```

Is there a reason for this inconsistency or is this just a legacy issue?

Comment: usr means "unix system resources", not "user"

Comment: Rubbish. That's a backronym. See early manuals like http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/v3/ where directories such as /usr/dmr are used as examples (dmr is Dennis M Ritchie, a co-creator of Unix). Clearly, /usr is where user directories were located.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Which of the following looks more like a *nix directory structure to you?

I suspect the mainstream distros these days are more concerned with the question "which of the following is the slightest bit user-friendly?" Linux distributions like Fedora and Ubuntu are attempting to attract mainstream, non-programmer users, and things like this are a good step in that direction.

`bin`, `lib`, `tmp`, `usr`, etc. are generally not exposed to average (i.e. "my mother") users, so leaving them abbreviated doesn't harm usability. The home directory, though, is something that every user is going to encounter, so it makes sense to have it easily human-readable.

Comment: Good point, although I think that's a slippery slope.  If you make all your decisions based on what your uninformed users want you'll get Windows.

Comment: That's it's own slippery slope - at which level of "uninformed" do we start ignoring user feedback? Must they be able to code assembly to be listened to? Ultimately, calling the downloads folder "Downloads" instead of the obtuse "dls" really harms no one and benefits plenty.

Comment: @Brad: usability makes or breaks an app/system.  I'd hazard a guess that the (vast) majority of people would know what "Downloads" means as opposed to "dls".

Comment: If they could the world would be a better place.  Disclaimer: I can't code assembly either. :)  I agree with you but I'm a user too, whatever my level of informed is.  If linux isn't the informed users system then what is?

Comment: Why limit Linux's obvious benefits to only a tiny subset of the population? An operating system can be friendly to informed and uninformed users at the same time, and it's well worth the effort.

Comment: I completely agree with brad... if you always listen to least experienced users you will get windows. Just look at some of the distros... and lxde manager (http://wiki.lxde.org/en/File:LXDE_desktop_full.png) - I see windows everywhere o_O

Comment: @Phil If you don't want it usable, you can always roll your own distro. The Linux community would be moronic to ignore genuine usability improvements.

Answer (score 3):

If I look at my home folder, I see countless folders and files starting with a dot and consisting mostly of lowercase letters. I don’t like having this mess in the home folder and seeing these capitalised folders gives me a comforting feeling that it *is* possible to organise and structure things in a good way.

Don’t see anything wrong with capitalised folders at all. But then, I also use spaces and unicode characters for files when it makes things more readable.

Comment: Normally dotfiles are hidden.

Comment: I knew someone would be saying that… — True, but a messy room is a messy room even with your eyes closed. (Well, there are also countless visible, undotted files in my home but that’s maybe another story. That *might* not be the OS’s fault…)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [xdg-user-dirs](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs) to tell applications to use your shortened names. There are some apps that forget to check if the locations are non-standard, but since it's an i18n issue you should get a good response if you file bugs.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to make the directories in the home directory space more user friendly because probably nothing cares what they are called except a few end user programs in KDE or Gnome.  You can't do similar things to something like /usr or /etc because there are literally thousands of programs that may or may not break if you made that change.

Comment: `/usr` and `/etc` are also not commonly exposed to basic users. Something mass-market like Firefox is going to expose its `/etc` config options in a UI within the app as well as in the text file.

Comment: @ceejayoz: a mass-market *app* like Firefox is gonna stick config options in some dotfolder in the user's home directory like it should, and won't stick *anything* in `/etc` ..

Comment: OK, use a different app for the example. You get the point, though.

Comment: The main kind of software that uses `/etc` for its configuration is server software. Applications generally store preferences and config in the home directory (hidden in a folder like `.appname`), or in the applications folder (in the case of some windows ports).

Answer (score 2):

Most people seem to like it when it's very clear what a directory is for - would you know what a dls directory was for if you hadn't created it yourself?

These directories you describe, with the exception of Desktop, aren't actually needed by any software I have come across.  You can just rename them and any software you use tends to remember the directory you last used.

The difference between Desktop and desk is just one keypress if you are using bash tab-completion, for all the Windows-converts who are scared of the big black box of a shell prompt it makes absolutely no difference time-wise and it is much more user-friendly.  I think one extra keypress is worth this user-friendlyness.

Comment: Hell, it doesn't even have to be an extra keypress. "De[Tab]" vs. "de[Tab]".

Comment: It is an extra keypress because you need to press the shift key.

Comment: "set completion-ignore-case on". :)

Comment: Aw, crap, @kaerast, you're right!

Comment: But it’s an extra keypress that costs no extra time when done right.

Answer (score 2):

This may have become widespread first on Mac OS X, which mixed the "cryptic" Unixy stuff with the more "user-friendly" names; not only in each user's directory, but at the root: /System, /Applications, etc. I find it to be a useful distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. You can edit the paths there, or just use the `xdg-user-dirs-update` command, e.g.

```
mv ~/Downloads ~/dls
xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOAD /home/$USER/dls
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather suspect that the big name distros are more concered with the question "which of the following is the most Windows/Mac like".

Comment: ... "which is more user friendly", yes. More mac/windows like, no. I don't think they're necessarily the same thing :P.

Answer (score 1):

Programmers/system administrators on UNIX systems use command line tools a lot, so it's not surprising that most of the directories used by them have been abbreviated for their convenience, as they'd be typing them a lot.  More so if you consider that in the beginning of UNIX, physical teletypes were in use.

In a GUI, you don't have to type anything most of the time, so having longer, clearer, friendlier names is more viable.

Of course, by using tab completion or symlinks, everyone can be happy, but I can't blame GUI designers for assuming or envisioning that normal users will do less typing of names, and not care about their length, as opposed to administrators/programmers.

Most of the directories you mention, like Downloads, etc. AFAIK are actually put there and recognized by your desktop environment.  Without a desktop environment, Linux doesn't really put very much in your home directory.  I'm sure they are configurable, you may want to read the documentation for whatever desktop environment/file manager you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's Linux. If you don't like the way a distro does something, you're encouraged (that is, *expected*) to create your own.